# How to import functions with the same name from different modules?

Tags: python

For example, something like this:

```
import module.main
import module2.main

module.main()
module2.main()
```

Would it be possible to import specific functions from different modules, but be able to differentiate them if they have the same name by a syntax such as the one above?

Comment: `import module.main as module_main; import module2.main as module2_main`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the motivation for wanting to avoid `import module; import module2`?

Comment: having multiple modules with the same function names, optimizations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `as` to assign a new name:

```
import module.main as main1
import module2.main as main2

main1() # module.main()
main2() # module2.main()
```